# Book title help YA romance

Tags: story-identification, books

Does anyone know the book where it has slaves and people with powers, a slave girl gets to know the prince but he doesn't know who she is, they have an arena where the people with power (special abilities) fight and she gets chosen to serve at the match and tries to avoid the prince but then she falls in the pit and her powers manifest and the prince is in Awe etc? I've been looking forever!

Comment: Can you recall any other details? These sound fairly generic.

Comment: Its based in a non-tech environment where she lives. I think she is red headed, not sure, there are "creatures" that they are afraid of but keep sending people out there and they don't come back.  I believe..  Thanks!

Comment: see this post to help you add any extra information to assist in identification: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: Both answers are not officially accepted in the system, but sport comments by the querent stating it is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This just ***might*** be The Red Queen by Victoria Aveyard.

> Mare Barrow's world is divided by blood—those with red and those with silver. Mare and her family are lowly Reds, destined to serve the Silver Elite whose supernatural abilities make them nearly gods. Mare steals what she can to help her family survive, but when her best friend is conscripted into the army, she gambles everything to win his freedom. A twist of fate leads her to the royal palace itself where, in front of the king and all his nobles, she discovers a superhuman ability she didn't know she had.

She meets the silver crown prince Cal without knowing his identity or disclosing her own. She falls into the pit where the Queenstrial is held. She displays electrokinetic powers even though being a lowly red.
Finally, many reds are conscripted to fight in the endless a war with the northern Kingdom of Lakeland and either return maimed or not at all.

References:
http://redqueen.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Queen
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Queen_(novel)

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping I wasn't mixing books together lol 

Comment: @Meg glad to help! Better yet, it is a growing series. BTW If this is the correct answer please consider accepting it, that will show later visitors of the site it is confirmed to be the right answer.